# Bandpass filter with a changing passband

Tags: filters, audio, bandpass, electrical-signal

**The problem**:

I have a signal that contains multiple, relatively stable frequency components and I want to extract only one of them. I attached a plot that illustrates the situation with a simple example. The top plot shows the raw signal and the lower one the spectrogram for the signal.

[image: Example with two frequency bands]

The emphasis here is on "relatively", since individual frequency bands are sometimes modulated upwards, crossing other frequency bands. By tracking the frequency bands on a spectrogram, I can approximate this frequency change. But this leaves me with a signal with a much lower sampling rate constrained by the nfft of the spectrogram. However what I want is the raw signal for just the frequency component of interest. Ideally, I would be able to compute the instantaneous frequencies for every frequency band. I am aware that this will be very noisy in situations where the frequency bands cross, but the majority of the signal would be useful at least. Hence, I need a filter, that can filter in boundaries (illustrated by the black dashed lines) that change over time.

**What I've tried**

I've naively tried implementing a rolling bandpass filter using scipy.signal, which obviously didn't work. I have also found another [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36408/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-moving-bandpass-filter-algorithm) that asked something similar but my research in that direction, particularly into Kalman filters, was not all that successful.

I am not looking for a finished solution but maybe a hint or resources to learn more from that might lead me into the right direction.

PS: I am a biologist by training and have very limited background in signal processing so please be nice to me :)

Comment: Perfectly doable: [1](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/tree/master/examples/ridge_extraction), [2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83742/50076) (Ctrl + F `practical`)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon thank you very much! I've spend the afternoon reading your code and examples, very nice! Am I right that I need to (1) do a ssq-cwt, then (2) come up with a reconstruction band (center frequency and a width around that) and (3) apply the issq-cwt to get back a reconstructed signal that only contains what is inside my reconstruction band. Is this correct? I'll try to implement this tomorrow ...

Comment: That's exactly right, and it can also work with `cwt` with a few differences that can be seen in `icwt` vs `issq_cwt`. In the second link I provide a tool that allows manually drawing curves on a saved image, and converting that to an array as coordinates, though it's unfinished.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Nice! I experimented a bit and all goes well until I try to invert the signal back. I always get the error 'Could not find converging or non-negligibly-valued bounds of integration for `int_fn`'. I've played with a bunch of different parameters and I do not seem to get past that point. Do you have any hints on how to deal with this? The code can be found [here](https://github.com/weygoldt/gridprepro/blob/master/fakegrid/fish_extraction.py).

Comment: Sounds like a bug report, not so much a deal for StackExchange comments.